# Error appearing while running R code: no 'dimnames' attribute for array

Tags: r, neural-network

I am trying to predict outcomes using. neuralnetwork. I am using the r package **neuralnet**, and when running the following code, I receive the error:

```
library(neuralnet)
new.output = compute(nn1, covariate=matrix(c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,

                                              0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,
                                              0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,
                                              0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,
                                              0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,
                                              0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,
                                              0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,
                                              0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,
                                              0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
                                              0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,
                                              0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,
                                              0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,
                                              0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,
                                              0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
                                              0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,
                                              0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,
                                              0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,
                                              0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,
                                              1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
                                              1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,
                                              1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,
                                              1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,
                                              1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0), nrow = 23, ncol = 10))
```

> Error in newdata[, object$model.list$variables] :    no 'dimnames'
>   attribute for array

What could be causing this? I have done this before with more rows and columns and it worked perfectly.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: From the help page of `compute`: ... The function `compute` is __deprecated__. Please refer to the new function `predict.nn`. And maybe you could specify what your `nn1` object is or how you create it?

Comment: Here is the code used to create nn1:

nn1=neuralnet(Event~var1+var2+var3+var4+...+var10, data = HNN1, hidden = 2, act.fct = "logistic", linear.output = FALSE)

each variable above and in the base dataset HNN1 is binary

Comment: Please edit your question with this new information. Also show the output of `str(HHN1)`, in your edited question.